# Java: How am I supposed to close async appender wrapped in SLF4J facade?

Tags: java, logging, asynchronous, slf4j, appender

I am  developing my own simple logging system, which I'd like to design so it writes the to output stream asyncronously. For that purpose I create processing thread. How am I supposed to  properly stop it, when user application finishes executing?

Unfortunatelly SLF4J facade doesn't provide any interface for me to delegate this responsibility to the user.

Comment: Look at how logback does it.  You can always attach a shutdown hook.

Comment: This has IMO always been a problem with Java logging frameworks.  They bind to the whole JVM.  No way that you can run two logging systems concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the thread daemon and it will finish togehter with the application. As for closing the OutputStream you don't need to worry about it. If it is a file or a socket it will be closed by OS anyway. Just make sure you flush after each write.